# Historical electricity prices for countries

Tags: data-request, global, prices, energy

Is there a source for national electricity prices for current and preceding years/ months for individual or grouped countries? I would like them in a standardized measure but national currencies is good enough and just adds an additional conversion step.

Comment: Do you mean wholesale prices (market trading) or retail prices (what end-customers pay)?

Comment: Ideally both, but either would be acceptable

Comment: retail prices are usually tariffs and either a yearly flat price, or two-tiered (peak and offpeak hours) which doesn't fluctuate throughout the year (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_pricing) for more info). I think wholesale energy prices would be more interesting, and probably the most useful is the spot auction price, which is hourly and divided between markets/countries.

Comment: All good, but I still need to identify (any) source :)

Comment: Great answers for Europe. Anything around for South America, North America, Asia, Australia and Africa?

Comment: not my area, but you if there are markets than the prices are usually online, if only difficult to scrape/collect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [European Energy Exchange](https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power) (EEX) is a marketplace for European energy (electricity), both futures and spot prices (although most trading is done either with brokers or as [OTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_(finance))). From your question it sounds like you are looking for spot auction prices, which are traded the day before delivery and have hourly resolution. That means each hour of the day has one settled price and volume. Multiple markets/countries have individual prices. The markets trading on [EPEX](http://[EPEXSpot][3]) Germany/Austria, Switzerland, France, UK, Netherlands, Belgium. [EPEX prices are available](https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/spot-market/auction#!/2017/05/31) from the parent company, EEX. Unfortunately, only individual days are available, so you can either copy/paste one by one, or scrape the HTML (*hint:* there is a json file somewhere in the source code)

[image]

A portion of this data is available on Quandl ([energy data documentation](https://blog.quandl.com/energy-data)). [Here's an example](https://www.quandl.com/data/EEX/PHDBSA-Phelix-Power-Spot-Auction-Day-Base-PHDBSA-EEX) of average daily prices in Germany/Austria from 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my other answer describing spot auctions, the [Nordic electricity trading market](http://www.nordpoolspot.com/How-does-it-work/Day-ahead-market-Elspot-/) has a data portal and exports available, specifically for day-ahead hourly prices.

**[ELSPOT DAY-AHEAD PRICES](http://www.nordpoolspot.com/Market-data1/Elspot/Area-Prices/ALL1/Hourly/?view=table)**

Here's a picture of the [bidding areas](http://www.nordpoolspot.com/How-does-it-work/Bidding-areas/)

[image]